# Pandoc and Abbreviations

Tags: html, pandoc

I'm trying to generate an ePub file with abbreviations. Here's an example:

`input.md`:

```
---
title: Test
language: en
---

# Test

HTML is maintained by W3C.
```

and `abbr.md`:

```
*[HTML]: Hyper Text Markup Language
*[W3C]:  World Wide Web Consortium
```

and `get-epub.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
pandoc -f markdown+abbreviations -t epub\
--abbreviations="abbr.md"\
"input.md" -o "output.epub";
```

I'm expecting to see something like this in the `output.epub` file:

```html
<p>
<abbr title="Hyper Text Markup Language">HTML</abbr> is maintained by <abbr title="World Wide Web Consortium">W3C</abbr>.
</p>
```

while the actual output is:

```html
<p>
HTML is maintained by W3C.
</p>
```

Did I miss something here?

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the abbreviations file is to list all words which serve as abbreviations, but only to adjust typography for those (like adding non-breaking spaces, not treating the dot as the end of a sentence, etc.)

The syntax in your example is not supported by pandoc. (Where is it from?)

There are plugins ("filters" in pandoc lingo) which should allow you to generate the desired outcome. Example: https://github.com/dsanson/pandoc-abbreviations.lua